# Linode backup for Heroku

Tags: heroku, nginx, unicorn

How would I go about setting up a backup for heroku downtimes set up on a vps like linode? (using nginx/unicorn)

Answer (score 1):

Essentially very simply, but also with a whole world of hurt.

Simply create an instance of your application of said VPS.

Then you need to ensure that you're able to flip your DNS from Heroku to said VPS without waiting for a TTL to expire, or someway of letting the world know your application has moved.

Then figure out a reliable way of ensuring that the code on both environments is exactly the same, and works on both different server setups

Then figure out how you can keep the data up to date in both environments so that when you do need to flip, the data will be the same in both environments.

Then you need to figure out a way to remind yourself to keep this secondary VPS up to date from a server management point of view.  Software updates, security patches etc etc.

Then you need to figure out a way that you can notified when Heroku is down 24/7

Then you need to hope that when Heroku is down that Linode isn't

... or just accept that any host will go down, and it can cost a hell of a lot of money to ensure that your site doesn't.  To be honest, it's probably better for you to look at some sort of hosting setup that allows redundancy and failover across several locations (which won't be cheap)

Answer (score 0):

There are third party services which provide the ability to keep your site (parts of) up if your server goes down - At least it appears to the user that your site is up but it's not working properly behind the scenes. [CloudFlare](http://www.cloudflare.com/index) is one such service. It sits in front of your site/application and performs magic (quite simply). It works with static/dynamic sites - and if your server goes offline then they are able to serve static parts of your site. See http://support.cloudflare.com/kb/what-do-the-various-cloudflare-settings-do/what-does-enabling-cloudflare-offline-browsing-do